# cant remove selected only from table - angular

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/WFONNlAEIeN8K9DEJCqV?p=catalogue

i traying to delete/remove only the selected row
but no success.

remove function

```
$scope.removeTrainee = function(trainee){
    var removeTrainee = $scope.trainees.indexOf(trainee);
    $scope.trainees.splice(removeTrainee, 1);
};
```

the select function

```
    $scope.selectedRow = null;  // initialize our variable to null
    $scope.setClickedRow = function(index){  //function that sets the value of selectedRow to current index
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
  };
```

tried to implement the selectedrow in ng-if or ng-click with && sign
no nothing

**the remove function works, but not with selected one**.
help please

Answer (score 0):

To take the row selected you `$scope.selectedRow` so your funcion should be something like this:

```
 $scope.removeTrainee = function(trainee){
    var removeTrainee = $scope.trainees.indexOf(trainee);
    $scope.trainees.splice($scope.selectedRow, 1);
};
```

Anyway I recommend you inplement the delete function in another way, more intuitive, for example adding a class to the selected row after clicking in it or adding a new row with a checkbox, to know which row is selected.

And you could also inprove your addTrainee function:

```
$scope.addTrainee = function(){
  $scope.trainees.push(
     $scope.newTreinee
  );  
    $scope.newTreinee = {};
};
```

Hope this solution helps you.